# Create selector UI for many applescript's?

Tags: applescript

i'm newbies with AppleScript and i wanted to create an UI Selector for many of AppleScripts.

Example, i've testA.scpt, testB.scpt, testC.scpt and i want to run just one of these scripts by choosing from a list of choices in a window (UI).

it's possible ?

so, it's possible, could you help me and give an example !?

i think is a very similar code but i'm not sure :

```
set theName to (choose from list {"testA", "testB", "testC"})
if theName is false then
    display dialog "You clicked cancel to exit." with icon stop buttons {"Exit"} default button {"Exit"}
else
    set theName to (item 1 of theName)
    display dialog theName with icon note buttons {"Info"} default button {"Info"}
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. It's based on your scripts being in the same directory as this script.

```
set theName to (choose from list {"testA", "testB", "testC"})

if theName is false then
    display dialog "You clicked cancel to exit." with icon stop buttons {"Exit"} default button {"Exit"}
else
    set theName to (item 1 of theName)

    tell application "Finder"
        set the_script_path to ((container of the (path to me)) as text) & theName & ".scpt"
        set the_script to load script alias the_script_path
    end tell

    run script the_script       
end if
```